# Sending Custom TableViewCell Action to UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Working on a small iOS app, and I made a custom tableview cell (and its own class) for my UITableView. Two of the things on the cell are "Add" and "Remove" button. When these are clicked, I need to update an array object that is in the UITableView, but because the table cell is a separate class, how can I send those changes over to the UITableView class?

For example, the code below is for my "remove" button on the cell:

```
- (IBAction)decrementItem:(id)sender {
    int count = (int)[self.specificItemCount.text integerValue];
    //Cannot have negative amount of food
    if(count == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        count--;
        self.specificItemCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count];
    }
```

But I need to update my array object in my table view when that button is clicked, how can I do that?

Comment: You need to write a delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Define a protocol on your cell class that your tableview class will implement. Here's an example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ios/ios_delegates.htm. Then set your tableview as a delegate on the cell (make sure to use a weak reference).

Comment: Why should I make sure to use a weak reference?

Comment: A strong reference to your tableview inside your tableviewcell will create a retain cycle - meaning both views will be stuck in memory, even once you're done using them. Your tableview will already have a strong reference to the cells, so the cell only needs a weak reference to the tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Use delegate or block.
If you only have one cell to operate, I recommend you use a block.

Define block, call when needed

```c
// CustomCell.h
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^addBlock)(NSString *text);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^removeBlock)(NSString *text);
@end

// CustomCell.m
- (IBAction)decrementItem:(id)sender {
    int count = (int)[self.specificItemCount.text integerValue];
    //Cannot have negative amount of food
    if(count == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        count--;
        self.specificItemCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",count];
    }
    if (removeBlock) {
        removeBlock(self.specificItemCount.text)
    }
}
```

Write the operation you need inside

```c
// VC.m
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath == customIndexPath) {
        CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        __weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
        cell.removeBlock = ^(NSString *text) {
            __strong typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
            // operation
        };
        cell.addBlock = ^(NSString *text) {
            __strong typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
            // operation
        };
        return customCell;
    }
    // ······
}
```